# Getting row id of table which comes from for loop

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table which comes from for loop as follows:

```
<c:forEach var="user" items="${usermap}">

            <tr>

                <td>${user.getUserName()}</td>
                <td>${user.getIsActive()}</td>
                <td id="status">${user.getBadLoginAttempts()}</td>
                <td class="cellCenter"><a id="unlockBtn" href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Unlock</a></td>




            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

So currently I have 15 rows . what I am trying to do here is, by clicking `unlock` button the status has to change in the 3rd column. for that I am calling jquery Ajax call as follow,

```
<script>
 $("#unlockBtn").onclick(function (e) { //user types teacherId on inputfiled
   //get the user id
   alert("button clicked");
             $.post('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/controller/UserController',{'userId':userId},
                function(data)
                {
            $('.status').html(data);
                });

});
```

The problem I am facing here is, since the table is generating dynamically I am unable to get user id. How can I get it? Can someone help me in this please?

Comment: invalid Markup generation as you have repeated same ids multiple times.

Comment: anchor would be having duplicate ids. thats invalid DOM.

Comment: yes I know ., pls help me in solve this. .

Comment: change `id` attribute of `td` to `class` and put the anchor's id in the class names, then refer them with class names instead.

Comment: @Jai k . . but how can i send user id to controller.

Comment: Thats what i was about to ask form where you are getting this `userid`?

Comment: @Jai it is in `user` object i can get as `user.getId()`

Comment: @Jai can I write like this `<td id=user.getId()>user.getUserName()</td>`

Comment: @user3599482 okay! then this would do better. as if you do like this then you can do as i am going to update my answer wait for a while plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have repeated same ids multiple times so that creates an invalid markup which causes unexpected behaviour in different browsers, so to overcome this issue you can change/put ids to class names:

```
<c:forEach var="user" items="${usermap}">
     <tr>
        <td>user.getUserName()</td>
        <td>${user.getIsActive()}</td>
        <td class="status">${user.getBadLoginAttempts()}</td> <!--id to class-->
        <td class="cellCenter">
            <a href="#" class="btn unlockBtn btn-sm btn-primary">Unlock</a>
        </td> <!-------------------^^^^^^^^^----placed id in the class-->
     </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

as you are using jquery so you have to change is little bit:

```
$(function(){ // dom ready function its required.
   $(".unlockBtn").click(function (e) { // bind the event with className selector
       var $this = $(this);
       alert("button clicked");
       $.post('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/controller/UserController', {
         'userId': $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text()
       }, // do this post id-^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       function (data) {
           $this.closest('tr').find('.status').html(data);
       });
   });
});
```

---

### Issues with your code in markup and jQuery:

#### Markup:

You have placed an id to some elements so within loop it gets repeated in every iteration which causes an invalid HTML generation. Issue with this is if you tell the browser to get the id of `XXX` then it stops the lookup for the other ids when it encounters first id in the markup.

### jQuery:

You have an invalid way of binding of click handler `onclick` is not available that way, either you can bind the event like this:

```
$(".unlockBtn").on('click', function (e) {
```

or

```
$(".unlockBtn").click(function (e) {
```

Comment: SHouldn't it be `$(this).siblings(".status")` instead of `$(".status")`? Otherwise, you'll change status in every column

Comment: sorry .., where exactly put ids in 3rd colom or after btn

Comment: I m trying it but alert is not comming. is this jquery .

Comment: @user3599482 you have to wrap your code within document ready handler as i suggested in the answer, and do include jQuery before this script.

Comment: @Jai sorry jai I dont have userId , I have `user name` only . I ahve to pass username what are the changes I have to do

Comment: change to this `'userId': $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text()` this will give you the user name of the first td in the parent tr of the clicked anchor.

Comment: Thank you so much . . I got better idea now

Comment: you are welcome @user3599482. You can accept it if this helped you solving your issues. Thanks.

Comment: @Jai its working fine dude , i m getting name , it goes to controller & changes the value but I cant able to change the text of 3rd column, I mean status. in my servlet controller after db operation i m just writing `out.println("Acitve");` but it is not changing status.

Comment: @Jai no dude its not working you just removed braces for this rt

Comment: No i declared a var at the top which holds the target element which is been clicked `var $this = $(this);` this is called caching of selectors.

Comment: @Jai can you please look at my another problem. It is also related `for loop`. I posted new question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you are looking for this kind of solution. Check my jsfiddle below.

```
$('#unlock').click(function(){    
$(this).parent().siblings('#test').html("TEEST");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EcN8h/3/)

Comment: exactly but it changes only first row

Comment: @user3599482 That what i mentioned in my answer, browser stops the lookup when id  is found, it never go for the other ids.

Comment: is it just javascript or jquery. . .

Comment: @Jai how can I overcome it. .

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle. Check it now. I am using jquery.

Comment: @user3599482 change `id` to `class` take a look at the other answer, which i have posted and updated.

Comment: Now it is working for all the row. Check my updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/EcN8h/3/